# How to pinpoint what part of my code is making a library raise a compile-time error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to compile a project and am getting the following error

[image]

It goes away if I suppress the warning by defining a macro

```
#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

How can I pinpoint what part of my code is using that library in a way that is making it angry like that? Double clicking the error takes me to the `xutility` file, which is not very helpful.

Edit: The error description is `Error   C4996   'std::copy::_Unchecked_iterators::_Deprecate': Call to 'std::copy' with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'`

Comment: If I lack the power of sight, how am I to know what the error message is? Please use words, not images.

Comment: Does the message not expand? There should be more information following that.

Comment: I just edited the question to add the error description. It is not the error itself that I am confused about, but how to figure out what in my code is throwing it.

Comment: There is supposed to be a line (a second line in the error's text, or it may manifest as a second error actually, though obviously it hasn't here) telling you which file and line triggered it. I don't have the IDE in front of me so I'm afraid I can't tell you how to find it.

Comment: This is - for me - the most frustrating thing about Visual Studio. It frequently doesn't give enough information in the compile errors to be able to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I would start by looking for where you use std::copy. The documentation about checked iterators explains the warning.